# Cache and Improve performance of JpaRepository method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the below code.I am using SPRING BOOT and JAVA 8

```
@Repository
public interface LogRepository  extends JpaRepository<Log, Integer>{



    List<Log> findByDate( Date date) ;
```

findByDate is returning me suppose 1 million records.findByDate( Date date) method gets fired whenever user is hitting the url /api/get/logs.

How can I keep the data in cache ?I don't want to hit the database every time method findByDate( Date date) is called.

Comment: In the given example you find only a single user (not a collection). That means that the date has to be unique, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: its list.i will correct

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: You need to add @EnableCaching annotation with @SpringBootApplication in your main class.

Step 2: Add @Cacheable annotation in your method like below

```
@Cacheable(value="user", key="#date")     
User findByDate( Date date) ;
```

For more details regarding the different cache configuration, you can follow be https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-cache-example/

Comment: what if some data changes in the database.?

Comment: If the key is the same, in your example 'date', then it will not fetch from the database again. For other keys which is not present in Cache map for that again database query will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here a great guide about caching and eviction in spring boot https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial.
However, you shouldn’t cache 1000000 records from a single query. It’s too expensive and you may risk a socketTimeoutException or a 502 timeout from client/application server. You should implement pagination on your Services (already provided by JPA itself) and eventually cache the pages (pay attention to the updates - take also a look at cache merging annotations)

Comment: Thanks but how pagination helps?
Can putting @Batch(value=2000<any optimal number> ) in entity Log help?

Comment: Pagination allows you to retrieve and filter a subset of your data. So if you have to display hundreds of products, for example, you can display 10,20,50 at time. Here some nice explanations and examples: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination ,https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: what about annotation @Batch.Can it help in my case

Comment: I’ve never see that annotation, but I suppose that handles batch queries so is more useful on inserts and updates.